# Trouble performing Python unittest on class

Tags: python, unit-testing, class

I'm having trouble performing a simple unittest on a class I created. I'm getting this error:

AssertionError: <**main**.MathClass object at 0x7fc7e0340940> != 18

```
import unittest

class MathClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.result = 0

    def add(self, num, *nums):
        self.result += num + sum(nums)
        return self

    def subtract(self, num, *nums):
        self.result -= (num + sum(nums))
        return self


class MathTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def testAdd(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.result.add(4,5,9), 18)

    def setUp(self):
        self.result = MathClass()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your unit test you make a result object which is a `MathClass` object `:

```py
def setUp(self):
    self.result = MathClass()
```

You later invoke the `add` method of the MathClass object.
The problem is that your `add` method returns `self`, e.g. the Math object itself.

```py
def add(self, num, *nums):
    self.result += num + sum(nums)
    return self
```

Internally, the `MathClass.result` may be changed but `add` still returns the Math object.

Therefore your `assertEquals` check compares the Math object and an `int` (18). Which are not equal :)

If you want to keep your variable names you may create a local variable that gets the MathClass object's result and compares it to 18:

```py
def testAdd(self):
    self.result.add(4,5,9)
    value = self.result.result
    self.assertEqual(value, 18)
```

Or whatever other option you find more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great option and the explanation helped tremendously. I ended up keeping my code in `MathTest` and used `return self.result` in the `add` method of my `MathClass`